# Existence of square root of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does there exist a non-zero non-invertible matrix having square root?

I know if a matrix is invertible,then it has a square root. I want to know whether its converse is true. I wasn't able to find one counterexample, so I want to know if its converse is true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

'I know if a matrix is invertible,then it has square root' - Untrue, consider $[-1]$.

Comment: Well, working over $\mathbb{R}$ anyway (being pedantic, I know).

Comment: I thought $-1$ was a real number ...

Comment: I don't think invertibility has anything to do with it, as you can take the square root of 0. You need the eigenvalues to be nonnegative.

Comment: +1 for untrue. I gonna edit my question...thanks for enlightening me

Comment: No problem! Think my comment on eigenvalues was probably more helpful than the answer I gave.

Comment: If you consider $[-1]$ as an element of $M_1\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$, then this is not a counterexample. Again, just me being pedantic. It is clear from context that you are talking about real matrices.

Comment: Yes. Am I right in thinking that over $\mathbb{C}$ every matrix has a square root, by the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: @RichardMartin Hmm... I'm not sure, but maybe. Let's say the matrices are $n \times n$. So you treat the entries of a potential square root as complex variables, impose the matrix equation and get an algebraic set $V\left(J\right) \subset \mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ with points corresponding to the entries of a potential square root. Nullstellensatz gives you $I\left(V\left(J\right)\right) = \sqrt{J}$, and we want $V\left(J\right) \neq \emptyset$. If $V\left(J\right) = \emptyset$ then we must have $\sqrt{J} = \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_{n^2}]$, but then $J = \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_{n^2}]$...

Comment: ... not sure how to verify that can't happen though. Intuitively I can't see this ideal containing any constant polynomials, but I can't quite finish this one off.

Comment: Hmmm I was hoping to argue that as $J$ is a proper ideal, its zero-set is nonempty, which I thought was some form of the NSS over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: I come way after the discussion, but since I didn't see a final answer to Richard Martin's question, I'll say that the answer is yes, any invertible complex matrix has a square root. One way to prove it (I think) is to use the holomorphic functional calculus applied to the function $z\mapsto z^{1/2}$ defined through a cut of the complex plane with a ray that doesn't hit any eigenvalue of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let a matrix be symmetric and real. We define a square root of a matrix $A$ as $B$ if$$A=B^2$$According to Schur decomposition we know that $$A=QDQ^H$$ for some unitary $Q$ and diagonal $D$. Also define B as$$B=QD_1Q^H$$by substitution we obtain $$B^2=QD_1Q^HQD_1Q^H=QD_1^2Q^H=QDQ^H$$which leads to $$D_1^2=D$$ therefore all the entries of $D$ should be non-negative which means the the only necessary condition for a symmetric matrix to have a square root is non-negative semi-definition (not only being invertible, the matrix may also have many zero eigenvalues).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has a square-root
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\ 0&0\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I want a matrix which has square root but not invertible...matrix in ur example doesn't have square root